# What is the difference between granulatiion, mesogranulation, supergranulation and giant cells in sun's photosphere?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, sun

Help me understand the differences between granulation, mesogranulation, supergranulation, and giant cells and at what depth they are created.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.